# Equivalent of Using @Autowired Interface in java

Tags: java, spring, reflections

I have an interface ITestClass..and there are methds which implements ItestClass..While using in spring if i use @Autowired ITestClass itestClass,spring will find the implemented class and call the respective method from that class during runTime..how is that possible without spring and without using reflections..

Answer (score 3):

You use [@Inject](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html)
That is supposed to be the standard equivalent for JEE.

Furthermore, you can use it with Spring as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CDI](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=365) and [`@Inject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/inject/Inject.html) annotation.

The concept and the process to find the class that implements an interface. In other words is the [Dependency Injection](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html).

Generally, [CDI](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=365) is an specification applied in [JEE environment](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/partcdi.htm#GJBNR).